# Convert Word.InlineShape to Excel.Workbook c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, vsto

There are some excel.workbooks in Word document.

i can get Word.Inline shapes but i need to convert them to Excel.Application

```
Word.InlineShapes shapes=wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes;
```

Those shapes created via

```
wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject("MSGraph.Chart.8", excellApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

How can i convert them to Excel.Workbook again?

Also i tried ;

```
Word.InlineShapes shapes = wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes;

foreach(Word.Shape shape in shapes)
{
     Word.Chart chart = shape.Chart;
}
```

but it throws unimplemented exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Word.OLEFormat ole = shape.OLEFormat;
ole.Activate();
Excel.Workbook book = (Excel.Workbook)ole.Object;
```